# Gwt XMLParser Failed to parse error not well formed

Tags: xml, gwt, xml-parsing

I am using GWT and want to parse an xml file, but I get this 'Failed to parse error: not well formed'.

I am following the exact steps from: 
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML.html

I am using the same xml email message and has been saved to a local directory (c:/email_message.xml), so its well formed, and the message its giving me is incorrect.

Here is what I got so far:

```
try
{
String xmlString = "c://email_message.xml";
Document xmlDoc = XMLParser.parse(xmlString);
}
catch (DOMException e)
{
Window.alert(e.getCause());
}
```

Thanks in advance. Help.

Comment: "so its well formed, and the message its giving me is incorrect." - I am skeptical of your position.

Comment: I doubled check too, well this is exactly what is in my xml doc

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<message>
  <header>
    <to displayName="Richard" address="rick@school.edu" />
    <from displayName="Joyce" address="joyce@website.com" />
    <sent>2007-05-12T12:03:55Z</sent>
    <subject>Re: Flight info</subject>
  </header>
  <body>I'll pick you up at the airport at 8:30.  See you then!</body>
</message>

I even used w3c validator, and it passed.

Comment: See my answer below - the problem is you need to load the file and then pass the contents into `parse`. `parse` will not load the file from a path for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLParser.parse` expects the xml as a string, not the file path to the xml. Load the file into a string and then pass that into `parse` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Serious, I was second thinking that too. But that seem inconvenient. Ill give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: That does the trick, after getting the doc returned as a string using RequestBuilder, the parse method worked as expected. Again thanks for the help.